# Bochs：attempt to read/write sector 2 with media not present

Tags: compilation

I am writing a BootLoader in virtualBox and using Bochs to debug，
Codes like that

```
mov ax,0x0820
mov es,ax
mov ch,0
mov dh,0
mov cl,2
mov ah,0x02
mov al,1
mov bx,0
mov dl,0x00
int 0x13



times (510-($-$$)) db 0
db 0x55,0xaa
```

but when i first debug the first line “mov ax，0x0820”
bochs show me like that

```
00017307933i[FLOPPY] attempt to read/write sector 2 with media not present
00025271896i[FLOPPY] controller reset in software
00025288589e[CPU0  ] read_virtual_checks(): read beyond limit
```

Can anybody help me？

Help me bro
Help me bro
Help me bro

Answer (score 1):

haha ,i found the answer.
in Bochs ,if you push the SpaceButton , the bochs will execute the last command you input
if you first input b 0x7c00
and input c
then the code jump the 0x7c00
if you press the spaceButton
it will recoginize it as "c" defaultly
c mean running untill meet the 0x7c00 which you set a interrupt(b 0x7c00)
so it will running forever untill you meet an error